# Using ng-show on an undefined value with ! causes the ng-show to by truthy

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to hide/show a `<p>` only when `model.Order.Enabled === false`, but if I use `ng-show` as I am below, then `model.Order.Enabled` will be `null` until the API get back with either `true` or `false`.  Then since my ng-show uses `!model.Order.Enabled` it evaluates to `!null` which Angular treats as truthy and therefore the `<p>` gets shown on in the DOM even though it may not supposed to be (if the API comes back and tells me the `model.Order.Enabled == true`)

```
<p ng-show="!model.Order.Enabled" style="color:#2660C6">Here is some text to show only when model.Order.Enabled === false</p>
```

This is causing my `<p>` to show for ~2 seconds while the API is still waiting for a response, then it just disappears afterwards.  Is this just a case where I have to add more logic inside the `ng-show` anywhere that this scenario occurs (which is a lot)?

Comment: You could just check explicitly? `ng-show="model.Order.Enabled==false"`

Answer (score 0):

To completely hide/show an element from the DOM use `ngIf` like so:

```
// let's suppose we're checking against foo.dataLoaded


<p ng-if="foo.dataLoaded">Element is displayed if truthy</p>
<p ng-if="!foo.dataLoaded">Element is displayed if falsey</p>
```

To take care of correct boolean value of your scope property, you should use a promise when getting the data. For example, you could start with $scope.foo.dataLoaded = false; and then inside a promise function you set it to true